# How can I plot the output of a PD compensator in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a simple PD compensator in a control loop. I want to see the compensator output step response. My code looks like this:

```
plant = tf(820,[0.08 1 0])

% PD Compensator
Kp = 2.25;
Ki = 0;
Kd = 0.025;
comp_pd = pid(Kp, Ki, Kd)

% plant with pd compensator
plant_pd = feedback(comp_pd*plant,1);
% pd compensator output
pd_output=feedback(comp_pd,plant);

figure();
step(plant_pd)
step(pd_output)
grid on;
ylim([-12 12]);
xlim([0 0.1]);
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
Error using DynamicSystem/step (line 95)
Cannot simulate the time response of models with more zeros than poles.
```

How can I plot the compensator output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because, as the error message suggests, the transfer function of an ideal PD compensator is not ["proper"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_transfer_function) and cannot be represented or simulated.

To work around this issue, it is common to practice to have an "approximate derivative" term, so that instead of having:

```
comp_pd = Kp + Kd*s
```

You have something like

```
comp_pd = Kp + Kd*s/(1+Tf*s)
```

This is the relevant section of the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pid.html) on the topic:

[image]

So in your code, simply replace:

```
comp_pd = pid(Kp, Ki, Kd)
```

by

```
comp_pd = pid(Kp, Ki, Kd, Tf)
```

where `Tf` is small, say `1e-3` although you may have to experiment until you find the right value depending on the time constant of your system.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful and points me in the right direction. I have been able to determine a suitable value for Tf in my system  but there is a little too much magic in the process for my liking.

the actual task is to find a PDF compensator equivalent to a phase lead compensator. They are equivalent but I am having a lot of trouble determining the equivalence.

I will search some more. 

Thanks again.